# Finding the price based on industry and number of transactions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to determine the price for my input table which has the specific industry type and the average monthly transactions based on the reference table 1 which has the price for different industries (these represent the A tier prices) and the reference table 2 which classifies the price tier based on the average monthly transactions..Reference table 1 has the price for pricing tier A for all the industries .. The price for tier B is calculated as 90% of price of Tier A price; the price for tier C is calculated as 90% of price of Tier B price and so on

**Input table**

| Industry | Avg Monthly Transactions |
| --- | --- |
| Automotive | 1129 |
| Financial Services | 7219 |
| Retail | 11795 |
| Financial Services | 10092 |
| Retail | 9445 |

**Reference table 1**

| Industry | price |
| --- | --- |
| Automotive | 35 |
| Financial Services | 40 |
| Retail | 30 |

**Reference table 2**

| Pricing Tier | Minimum Average Monthly Transactions | Maximum Average Monthly Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 100 |
| B | 101 | 1000 |
| C | 1001 | 2500 |
| D | 2501 | 5000 |
| E | 5001 | 10000 |
| F | 10001 |  |

**Output table**

| Industry | Avg Monthly Transactions | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Automotive | 1129 | 28.35 |
| Financial Services | 7219 | 26.24 |
| Retail | 11795 | 17.71 |
| Financial Services | 10092 | 23.62 |
| Retail | 9445 | 19.68 |

**Python Code Tried**

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df1=pd.read_csv("input.csv")
    df2=pd.read_csv("reference1.csv")
    df3=pd.read_csv("reference2.csv")

industry =df1[industry]
avgmonthlytransaction=df1[Avg Monthly Transactions]
price=df1.where(df1[avg Monthly Transactions]>=df3[min average] & <=df3[maximum average],pricingtier)
&& df1.where(df1[industry]=df2[Industry],df2[Price]
```

Comment: OK, so what is your *specific* question?

Comment: What have you tried or coded to achieve this or in which part you are getting errors?

Comment: Hi @MattDMo: I am trying to arrive at the output table based on the input table, reference table 1 and reference table 2 using python..I am new to python so wanted to get some guidance here

Comment: @vigneshkanakavalli: I will post the code that I tried now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df3['factor'] = [0.9**i for i in range(6)]
df3
```

[image]

Use `cut()` to create bins, find the corresponding `Pricing Tier`,
and we can map its `factor` via `df3`.

```
tier = pd.cut(
    df1['Avg Monthly Transactions'], 
    bins=(df3.iloc[:,1].values.tolist() + [np.inf]),
    labels=df3['Pricing Tier'].values.tolist())

tier = tier.to_frame(name='Pricing Tier')

output = df1.merge(df2, on='Industry', how='left')
output['price'] = output['price']*tier.merge(df3[['Pricing Tier','factor']], on='Pricing Tier', how='left')['factor']

###
             Industry  Avg Monthly Transactions    price
0          Automotive                      1129  28.3500
1  Financial Services                      7219  26.2440
2              Retail                     11795  17.7147
3  Financial Services                     10092  23.6196
4              Retail                      9445  19.6830
```

Comment: Thank you so much @baron legendre!..Really appreciate your help!...Can you please let me know how to just base it off the pricing tier and transactions alone with the pricing for tier A being 40 and 90% subsequent decrements

Comment: The core concept is we get to know the usage of `cut()` function: `cut(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, `arg2` would set the bins, `arg3` are their corresponding bins' name `Pricing Tier`, and `arg1` is the input `Avg Monthly Transactions` series, it'll return corresponding `Pricing Tier` base on each `Avg Monthly Transactions` inputs. Once we know the specific `Pricing Tier`, we know the `factor` that is gonna multiply the by the `price`. You can run the code into individual cells and observe outputs

Comment: At the final step, you might want to dissect what `tier.merge(df3[['Pricing Tier','factor']], on='Pricing Tier', how='left')` actually looks like.

Comment: @ Baron Legenre: I am getting the error '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str' when I try to implement the code tier = pd.cut(
    df1['Avg Monthly Transactions'], 
    bins=(df3.iloc[:,1].values.tolist() + [np.inf]),
    labels=df3['Pricing Tier'].values.tolist())  ..Do you have any suggestions

Comment: Does that probably mean your `df3`'s second and third columns or `df1['Avg Monthly Transactions
']` is not an integer type?  Could you check `df1.dtypes`, `df2.dtypes`, `df3.dtypes`, make sure that digits are not in str/object type.

Comment: Hi Baron Legendre: I should not have the price overwritten and rather have the old price and the newly calculated price ...Yes its Price and its resolved now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246818/discussion-between-user3369545-and-baron-legendre).